# Que esta pasando?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, parametros

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en JAVA / SWING para el escritorio con un sistema gestor de base de datos PostgreSQL. Ya tengo implementados varios informes sin problemas. Los mencionados informes toman los campos comumes como parametros (Logo, titulo, nombre de compania, editor, etc). Todo esto esta gestionado desde una clase (EngineReport.class). Luego he comenzado a implementar informes con un parametro (String) para aplicar filtros al conjunto de datos. Ahora necesito implementar parametros para multiples filtros (String, Integer, etc). Esto lo realizo mediante un metodo generico de la clase EngineReport. A continuación presento el código completo de la clase:

```
package com.m3dsa.gci.controller;

import com.m3dsa.gci.app.Inicio;
import com.m3dsa.gci.model.PostgreSQL;
import com.m3dsa.gci.view.Application;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

/**
 *
 * @author Elio Gabriel Drovandini
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class EngineReports {

    /**
     * Constructor por defecto
     */
    public EngineReports() {
        datos = PostgreSQL.getInstancia();
        conn = datos.getConeccionOn();
        parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor de clase
     *
     * @param recursoInforme Ruta relativa de recurso al informe de Jasper
     */
    public EngineReports(String recursoInforme, String titulo) {
        this();
        rutaRelativaRecurso = recursoInforme;
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    /**
     * Fija los parámetros de filtrado del informe
     *
     * @param <T> Parámetrización del método
     * @param nombreParametro Nombre de la variable en el informe Jasper
     * @param tipoParametro Tipo de datos de la variable de parámetro
     */
    public <T> void setParametros(String nombreParametro, T tipoParametro) {
        parametros.put(nombreParametro, tipoParametro);
    }

    private void setCampos() {
        rutaInforme = getClass().getResource(rutaRelativaRecurso).getPath().replaceFirst("/", "").replace("%20", " ");
        String app_denominacion = Inicio.appNombre + " V " + Inicio.versionApp;
        parametros.put("APP_DENOMINACION", app_denominacion);
        parametros.put("EMPRESA_LOGO", getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/empresa_logo.png"));
        String paramDomicilio = Inicio.comDomicilio + ", " + Inicio.comLocalidad + " - " + Inicio.comProvincia + " (" + Inicio.comPais + ")";
        parametros.put("EMPRESA_DOMICILIO", paramDomicilio);
        parametros.put("EMPRESA_CUIT", Inicio.cuit);
        parametros.put("EMPRESA_CORREO", Inicio.correo);
        String telFax = Inicio.telefono + " / FAX | " + Inicio.fax;
        parametros.put("EMPRESA_TELEFONOS", telFax);
        parametros.put("INFORME_TITULO", titulo);
        parametros.put("INFORME_EMISOR", Application.getUsuario());
    }

    /**
     * Ejecuta el informe del cual se ha pasado su ruta relativa a los recursos
     */
    public void getInforme() {
        /* Se personaliza el informe con los campos privados de la empresa */
        setCampos();
        try {
            informe = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(rutaInforme);
            JasperPrint impresora = JasperFillManager.fillReport(informe, parametros, conn);
            JasperViewer visor = new JasperViewer(impresora, false);
            visor.setDefaultCloseOperation(JasperViewer.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            visor.setTitle("GCI - Informe: " + titulo);
            visor.setVisible(true);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(InformeSinFiltros.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), Inicio.appNombre, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } finally {
            datos.setConeccionOff();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Ejecuta el informe incrustado en un JDialog para salvar el inconveniente
     * de la modalidad
     */
    public void getDlgInforme(JDialog base) {
        /* Se personaliza el informe con los campos privados de la empresa */
        setCampos();
        /* Se declara el dialogo contenedor del visor de informe */
        JDialog contenedor = new JDialog(base);
        try {
            informe = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(rutaInforme);
            JasperPrint impresora = JasperFillManager.fillReport(informe, parametros, conn);
            JasperViewer visor = new JasperViewer(impresora, false);
            contenedor.setContentPane(visor.getContentPane());
            contenedor.setSize(visor.getSize());
            contenedor.setResizable(true);
            contenedor.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            contenedor.setTitle("GCI - Informe: " + titulo);
            contenedor.setVisible(true);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(InformeSinFiltros.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), Inicio.appNombre, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } finally {
            datos.setConeccionOff();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gestiona la re-conexión a la BBDD
     */
    private void setReconexion() {
        try {
            if (conn.isClosed()) {
                conn = datos.getConeccionOn();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(CatalogoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), Inicio.appNombre, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    /* Declaración de campos de clase  de desarrollador */
    private PostgreSQL datos;
    private Connection conn;
    private String rutaRelativaRecurso, rutaInforme, titulo;
    private JasperReport informe;
    private JasperPrint impresora;
    private JasperViewer visor;
    private HashMap<String, Object> parametros;
    /* Fin de declaración de campos de clase de desarrollador */
}
```

He leido toda la documentación a cerca de este procedimiento pero obtengo unn error que muestro a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro entender que esta sucediento. He probado en cambiar el orden de los parametros, el tipo de datos de los parametros, etc. Como se puede ver en la excepcion los parametros no son tomados. Con el depurador de NetBeans se puede observar que el objeto parametro (HashMap) esta completo. No entiendo porque no funciona si en los informes anteriores lo hace sin problemas. Una observacion importante es: en el  editor SQL de jasperSoft Studio cuando implemento la condición WHERE para el parametro Integer no aparece en la lista de parametros disponibles, solo lo hace si cambio el tipo de dato del parametro a String. Desde ya gracias por su atención y aguardo su respuesta

Aquí dejo la traza del error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error preparing statement for executing the report query:

SELECT catalogo_productos_inf.id_componente,
    catalogo_productos_inf.fml_nombre,
    catalogo_productos_inf.id_cliente,
    catalogo_productos_inf.tps_nombre,
    catalogo_productos_inf.cliente,
    catalogo_productos_inf.id_producto,
    catalogo_productos_inf.pro_clase,
    catalogo_productos_inf.pro_categoria,
    catalogo_productos_inf.proveedor,
    catalogo_productos_inf.spc_ruteo,
    catalogo_productos_inf.prp_nombre,
    catalogo_productos_inf.spc_referencia,
    catalogo_productos_inf.spc_valor,
    catalogo_productos_inf.und_nombre,
    catalogo_productos_inf.und_simbolo
FROM catalogo_productos_inf
WHERE 
     catalogo_productos_inf.id_componente = ? 
     AND catalogo_productos_inf.id_producto = ? 
     AND catalogo_productos_inf.id_cliente = ?


    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createStatement(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:545)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:299)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1257)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:726)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.setParameters(BaseReportFiller.java:457)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:578)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:414)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:120)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:103)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:530)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:954)
    at com.m3dsa.gci.controller.EngineReports.getInforme(EngineReports.java:86)
    at com.m3dsa.gci.controller.event.CatalogoEVT.btnImprimirActionPerformed(CatalogoEVT.java:62)
    at com.m3dsa.gci.controller.event.CatalogoEVT.actionPerformed(CatalogoEVT.java:41)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.checkClosed(PgConnection.java:783)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.getMetaData(PgConnection.java:1237)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.OracleProcedureCallHandler.isOracle(OracleProcedureCallHandler.java:72)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.isProcedureCall(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:556)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createStatement(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:379)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega la traza del error completa y el código donde creas y llenas con datos el `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Mil gracias por responder, aquí pongo la traza del error:

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a la respuesta del amigo he podido encontrar el error. El inconveniente es que debido a como estructure mi proceso. Utilice una clase para generar todos los informes (con y sin filtros). Después de ingresar cada parámetro debo de chequear es estado de la conexión a la base de datos. Saludos y mil gracias a todos. Cuídense!!!!

Comment: Enhorabuena, pero te recomiendo que reetructures esta respuesta para que no te la cierren y de paso para que puedas ganar reputación.

Comment: Gracias, como puedo hacer lo que comentas?. Saludos

Comment: Agregando el código donde se vea cómo fue que resolviste el problema que tenías.

Comment: No tengo código puntualmente hablando. Es mas conceptual. Poseía un método para verificar la conexión a al base de datos. Solo tuve que llamar a este método antes de generar el informe.